# Authorization header missing when calling WCF web service on IIS 7

Tags: wcf, iis-7, authorization

We have a WCF web service that takes a "username:password" Authorization header. This service works fine on my development Windows 7 machine and on a Windows Server 2003 machine in production.

However, our development and new production servers are Windows Server 2008 and the service fails to receive the Authorization header.

You can see the raw request from Fiddler below includes the Authorization header.

> POST http://servername/service.svc/soap HTTP/1.1
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   **Authorization: test:test**
>   VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPozpQ7mbpOVRFu79Tl0h3mkIAAAAAJMavDzJlIkqyjJDSIIxdVuKNB0y6n29OvukFtyRt0wwACQAA
>   SOAPAction: "..."
>   Host: servername
>   Content-Length: 152
>   Expect: 100-continue
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Connection: Keep-Alive

I haven't successfully enabled IIS Advanced Logging to see if I can get any extra information on the server.

The IIS website is configured for anonymous authentication.

The service implements *IAuthorizationPolicy* and the *Evaluate* method is definitely being called, which is where the authorization information is missing.

It feels like I've misconfigured something in IIS, but I have no idea what! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When switching from Windows Server 2003 to 2008, did you also switch from IIS 6 to 7? If so, I suspect this has a lot more to do with the IIS version than the Windows Server version; you might consider changing the title of your question accordingly.

Comment: Good point. I'm also told by the former colleague who built the service that it did work on the development Windows Server 2008 server originally. That only makes this more frustrating.

Comment: Make sure the IIS server handles basic authorization, i think it is disabled by default.

Comment: This was missing on the production server, but was enabled on the development server. Doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was dealing with two different problems.

On the development server, I found that the .NET 4.0 installation was broken. This was diagnosed by this [brilliant tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx).

On both servers, I changed the pipeline mode from *Classic* to *Integrated*, as nobody knew why it was set to Classic in the first place. A few tweaks the web config later, and the service was working!

The solution may also have required Basic Authentication, as suggested by Richard L, since that was missing from the production server. Note that Basic Authentication is not enabled on the service web site itself.

A very frustrating few days trying to get this working.